# I tried doing a do while loop in this code but every time it loops back the rate increases is there any chance I can make stay only at 0.10?

Tags: c++

The problem with this code is that every time I loop, it back to start the rate increases and don't stay at a fix value of 0.10. like I finish my first run, the second time I repeat the code, the rate went from 25% as the last commission rate to 30%, the starting commission rate, to the new loop even.

My desire output only is:

Enter the sales: 2500

10% commission : Php 2500.00

15% commission : Php 3750.00

20% commission : Php 5000.00

25% commission : Php 6250.00

any fix for this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Gas_commission{
    private:
        float res_coms = 0, val_sales = 0, val_rate = 0.10;
    public:
        void get_info(){
            //input
            cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Enter the following to find the commission: " << endl;
            cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Enter Sales: ";
                cin >> val_sales;
            cout << "\n";
        }
        void get_res(){
            //output
            cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
            res_coms = val_sales * val_rate;
            cout << val_rate * 100 << "% " << "commission: Php " << res_coms << endl;
            val_rate += 0.05;  //the rate here keep increasing every time I loop the code
            }
        }
};
int main()
{
  Gas_commission SALE;
  char input;
  do{
    SALE.get_info();
    SALE.get_res();
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\nDo you want to retry again (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> input;
  } while (input == 'Y' || input == 'y');
}
```

Comment: Relying on user input opens the possibility of the user messing up your test. (Remember: the code in your question is to demonstrate your issue; it need not demonstrate your full functionality.) Since you used `2500` as your example, you could hardcode that into your [mre], as in `void get_info(){
val_sales = 2500;
}` -- or even just initialize `val_sales` to `2500` and skip the call to (and definition of) `get_info()`. Isolate the issue, and mock up whatever context is needed to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest solutions is to "reset" the variable `val_rate` to its starting default value in each call to `get_res()`:

```
void get_res(){
    val_rate = 0.10;

    // The rest of the code...
}
```

By doing this, the variable no longer needs to be a member variable, it can be a local variable inside the `get_res` function instead, which makes more sense. The result variable `res_coms` should be local as well.

---

Another option is to define the `SALE` variable *inside* your loop. Then it will be constructed and all the variables be reset to their default values each iteration of the loop.

Actually, I think a combination would probably be best: Define the `res_coms` and `val_rate` variables locally inside the `get_res` function, *and* define `SALE` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Gas_commission SALE;` should put in the do while loop to reinitialize your private attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- In your current `Gas_commission` class, the `val_rate` variable is only initialized to 0.1 once in `Gas_commission`'s constructor. To reset it each time `get_res` is called, you need to reset it at the start of that function:

  ```
  void get_res()
  {
       val_rate = 0.1;
       // ...
  }
  ```

  And while you're at that, note how `val_rate` is actually only used inside `get_res`! so you can move it from the class to the function; i.e.:

  ```
  class Gas_commission{
    private:
      float res_coms = 0, val_sales = 0;
        // ...
        void get_res()
        {
             float val_rate = 0.1;
             // ...
        }
  };
  ```
- An alternative to all of the above is to put the `SALE` object into your loop, then also the constructor (and therefore `val_rate`'s initialization) is done in each loop iteration:

  ```
  int main()
  {
    char input;
    do{
      Gas_commission SALE;
      SALE.get_info();
      SALE.get_res();
      cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
      cout << "\nDo you want to retry again (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> input;
    } while (input == 'Y' || input == 'y');
  }
  ```